# is markdown syntax capable to receive web response?

Tags: markdown

Is it possible for to use markdown syntax for getting a web response? I've been trying to look for various tutorials online but not seeing any sample info. You see we have a url "https://mywabsite/version" that response back the version "abcd321" only, it has no auth required and can be accessed simple curl command or browse in chrome. I was wondering if Markdown syntax is capable to have the same functionality same as curl

Comment: Markdown is a lightweight markup language so I think it is not designed to get data from a server for which curl is there

Comment: I'm not sure yet Amit about "not designed to get data from a server " but based from the tutorials online named "Markdown-Cheatsheet" provided by github, there is a syntax sample capable to get the logo of a specific url. I'm thinking that since it is able to grab the logo it should be also able to get the url/web response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in Markdown as-is, but you can "cheat" a little and show an image with some text automatically generated. You'll then have to show the image in Markdown pointing to your URL with something like:

```
![My Website Version](https://mywabsite/version)
```

This is done frequently in various situations, for example when showing build status on Github Repositories with Travis CI. The [Rails project](https://github.com/rails/rails) shows its build status using:

```
![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/rails/rails.svg?branch=master)
```

Which gives:

[image: Build Status]

An automatically generated SVG image showing some text. You may have to implement your own image generation logic, but that's another matter ;)

Comment: Thanks Pierre B. this really proves me wrong :-).  I forgot that the url that I need to hit is "https://mywabsite/version.html" I also tried it using the cheat format you provided and just give me the "My Website Version"

Comment: That is normal if the page return only text. For this to work your page must return some image format (SVG, JPG, GIF, PNG...). That's why you may have to implement your page to return an image instead of text ;)

Comment: http://shields.io/ provides badges for all sorts of known (to them) services. They also allow you to define custom badges, but those get hard-coded; you can't use any random URL as the source. However, their server and badge making lib is [open source](https://github.com/badges/shields), so you could run your own custom instance which worked with your own custom resource.